# How to make <head><title>...</title><head> translatable in layout definition

Tags: magento2, layout, localisation, page-layouts

Here I have the default contact page layout file (`contact_index_index.xml`):

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Contact Us</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

How can I translate the `head` title?

Answer (score 2):

**contact_index_index.xml**

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Contact Us</argument>
            </action>
    </referenceBlock>
<body>
```

Reference: `/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml`

Answer (score 1):

I use the following fix for this bug. You have to override Magento 2 Page renderer. Create a model file in your module `Company/Module/Model/Page/Renderer.php`:

```
<?php


namespace Company\Module\Model\Page;

class Renderer extends \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer {

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function renderTitle()
    {
        return '<title>' . $this->escaper->escapeHtml(__($this->pageConfig->getTitle()->get())) . '</title>' . "\n";
    }
}
```

And then add the following line to the `Copmany/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml` file:

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer" type="Company\Module\Model\Page\Renderer" />
```

Comment: Thanks man. This is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom theme, overwrite the page title in this layout file:
'`app/design/frontend/VENDOR/YOURTHEME/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml`'

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Kontakt</title>
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: Your code do overwrite title, but it does not translate it so if you change your locale it will stay 'kontakt'